# how to load view into another view codeigniter 2.1?

Tags: codeigniter, view, load

Ive been working with CI and I saw on the website of CI you can load a view as a variable part of the data you send to the "main" view, so, according the site (that says a lot of things, and many are not like they say ...ej pagination and others) i did something like this

```
$data['menu'] = $this->load->view('menu');
$this->load->view ('home',data);
```

the result of this is that I get an echo of the menu in the top of the site (before starts my body and all) and where should be its nothing, like if were printed before everything... I have no idea honestly of this problem, did anybody had the same problem before?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

1. Load it in advance (like you're doing) and pass to the other view

   ```
   <?php
   // the "TRUE" argument tells it to return the content, rather than display it immediately
   $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('menu', NULL, TRUE);
   $this->load->view ('home', $data);
   ```
2. Load a view "from within" a view:

   ```
   <?php
   // put this in the controller
   $this->load->view('home');

   // put this in /application/views/home.php
   $this->view('menu');
   echo 'Other home content';
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I was going to answer this question but my points of user doesnt allow me to do it... the problem was the third parameter FALSE, I didnt know ... thanks

Comment: thanks. Null is the most Important parameter in this condition.

Comment: Way 1 is simple and useful without any library. Thanks.

Comment: How can I load an array into the second view, so using your example 1 above $this->load->view('menu',DATA_ARRAY, TRUE)

Comment: @frobak you pass them thru explicitly $this->view('menu', compact('menu'));

Answer (score 7):

Create a helper function

```
function loadView($view,$data = null){
    $CI = get_instance();
    return $CI->load->view($view,$data);
}
```

Load the helper in the controller, then use the function in your view to load another one.

```
<?php 
...
    echo loadView('secondView',$data); // $data array
...
?>
```