# CodeIgniter: Passing variables between views

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say you load a view from a controller and that view loads another view that uses a lot of the same variables as the view that loaded it. How do get both views to share those variables? Thanks

Comment: @Vickel. Did you try to load view in another view?

Comment: @Vickel. No you didn't try. I have done in my projects to avoid redundancy, we make a single file and loaded in another view file too.

Comment: @kumar_v now I'm learning... can you please post an example?

Comment: @Vickel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1

Comment: I've just tried it out, you're right, it works! thanks for letting me know something new, very helpful, indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables you define to a view, are passed down to views loaded within the parent one. You don't need to pass them down an other level through the second array parameter, unless you want to override a specific value.

Basically, define all variable in the 2nd parameter to the "parent" view and both views will have these variables.

Answer (score 1):

For ex: you are loading view in **controller**:

```
$data["msg"] = "hi";
$this->load->view("view_file",$data);
```

In `view_file`, you are loading another **view file**

```
$this->load->view("view_file2",array("msg"=>$msg)); // here msg is extracted from first view file
```

Comment: Now way to just "relay" the variables?

Comment: I mean relay the whole set of variables without having to specify them one by one.

Comment: Yes you can do. It's all your logic. You can pass it as array.

Answer (score 1):

In one view, i set this:

window.variable= variableToAnotherView;

windows.variable is to pass the variable globaly, so you will be able to call it in another view.