# How to call multiple views in a single controller function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to call other views in single controller function and want to change one view on clicking the link.

For example when I click the about_us link it should be open the about_us and when I click on contact_us link it should be replaced with about_us view but whole views remain same using jQuery and ajax.I don't know about jQuery and ajax. How it possible to do this?

My view code is

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/about_us">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/contact_us">Company Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/faq">Why Choose Jan Japan</a></li>
```

my controller is

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('top_strip');
    $this->load->view('top_menue);
    $this->load->view('about_us');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: You can not load multiple views in a controller though you can load a view in another view. here is you detail answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1

Comment: first you need to write codes inside a function of a class. You cannot write code as you did.And you can load multiple view inside a controller.

Comment: @Haroon you are wrong.You can load multiple view from controller too.

Comment: @Shaiful You are quite correct. [Here is link](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html#adding-logic-to-the-controller) to documentation that proves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View(Header.php):

```
    <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/about_us" onclick="loadaboutus()">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/contact_us">Company Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/faq">Why Choose Jan Japan</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divDynamic"></div>
```

in this view i have written inline JavaScript

> onclick="loadaboutus()"

within  tag. so when user click on About Us link, loadaboutus() function of javascript will be call a controller's  `loadaboutus()` function.

Javascript-Ajax:

```
function loadaboutus()
{
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/loadaboutus",
                success: function (data) {
                   $('#divDynamic').html(data);
                }
            });
}
```

Controller:

```
function loadaboutus()
{
  $this->load->view('about_us');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three links:

1. /home
2. /contact_us
3. /faq

These are three separate controllers. When the links are clicked, the page is reloaded.

So you need three controllers.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('top_strip');
        $this->load->view('top_menu');
        $this->load->view('home_page');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

class About_us extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('top_strip');
        $this->load->view('top_menu');
        $this->load->view('about_us');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

class Contact_us extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('top_strip');
        $this->load->view('top_menu');
        $this->load->view('contact_us');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

This is probably not the ideal way of doing it however as you are a new it is a good learning step.

Comment: thanks
is it possible that creating three controllers. but clicking one link all views are not reloaded but contact_us will be display using ajax and jquery.???

Comment: You missed a `'` after `top_menu`probably copy from ops code where OP also made the same mistake.

Comment: Woops! You're right. Fixing this now. The response below is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to make a common file template.php with the following code:

```
   foreach ($views as $view) {
      $this->load->view($view);
   }
```

now to called it from controller :

just do the following :

```
public function index()
    {
        $data=array('view1'=>"include/header",
                    'view2'=>"top_strip",
                    'view3'=>"top_menu",
                    'view4'=>"contact_us",
                    'view5'=>"footer"
          );
        $this->load->view('template',$data);
    }
```