# How to load view from a different folder and pass it to the required view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I have installed the tank_auth to help me out in the login but I'm using codeigniter for the first time. I have loaded the library and called the view as follows in the main controller:

```
public function index()
{


    $this->load->library('tank_auth');    
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    $data['login_form'] = $this->load->view('auth/login_form', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('nav');
    $this->load->view('login',$data);

    $this->load->model('posts');       
    $data['post'] = $this->posts->get_post();        
    $this->load->view('posts',$data);

}
```

Then I wanted to load the setup as offered by tank_auth, but on the UI that I have made on the login page. But for some reason it doesn't work and I just get a blank page. "auth" is a folder in the views directory where other view(xyz.php) files are stored. How can I solve this and use the same tank_auth library in the UI and views that I have created?

[this is the code that I was using as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1)

Comment: Why can't you build your own login system instead using api to do that ?

Comment: I could, but then I assumed these libraries was the whole point of using a framework famous for fast completion of projects. Moreover the library offers many direct features which if used could reduce the effort immensely.

Comment: And the library made you stuck here. From my experience, Login System is really a very simple and interested thing to do :)