# CodeIgniter loading a view into a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to load a view into a view within CodeIgniter, but cant seem to get it to work.

I have a loop. I need to place that loop within multiple views (same data different pages). So I have the loop by itself, as a view, to receive the array from the controller and display the data.

But the issue is the array is not available to the second view, its empty

The second view loads fine, but the array `$due_check_data` is empty

SO, I've tried many things, but according to the docs I can do something like this:

Controller:

```
// gather data for view

$view_data = array(
   'loop' => $this->load->view('checks/include/due_checks_table', $due_check_data, TRUE),
   'check_cats' => $this->check_model->get_check_cats(),
   'page_title' => 'Due Checks & Tests'
);

$this->load->view('checks/due_checks',$view_data);
```

But the array variable `$due_check_data` is empty

I'm just getting this error, saying the variable is empty?

> Message: Undefined variable: `due_check_data`

Comment: You can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1

Comment: Yeah that doesnt work. I'm still getting an empty variable. I think the issue is passing the loop-array from the controller to the view

Comment: Is the problem passing multiple views?

Comment: No i can load the second view fine, but the array created within the controller is not making it to the second view, its empty

Comment: First make sure $combined_checks is not empty at controller

Comment: All the variables and arrays are fine and populated

Comment: Try with out TRUE. But I do not see any other data for $due_check_data like example `$due_check_data['title'] = 'Something';`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `$view_data` array to your view. Then, in your view, you can access only the variables contained in `$view_data`:

- `$loop`
- `$check_cats`
- `$page_title`

**There is no variable `due_check_data` in the view**.

---

**EDIT**

The first view is contained in the variable `$loop`, so you can just print it in the second view (checks/due_checks):

`echo $loop;`

If you really want to have the `$due_check_data` array in the second view, why don't you simply pass it?

```
$view_data = array(
   'loop' => $this->load->view('checks/include/due_checks_table', $due_check_data, TRUE),
   'check_cats' => $this->check_model->get_check_cats(),
   'page_title' => 'Due Checks & Tests',
   'due_check_data' => $due_check_data
);

$this->load->view('checks/due_checks',$view_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<?php`. Should be something like this

```
<?php echo $due_check_data; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller seems has no error. Check out some notices yourself:

```
<?=$due_check_data?>
```

This only available in **PHP >= 5.4**

```
<? echo $due_check_data; ?>
```

This only available when you enable short open tag in **php.ini** file but not recommended

Comment: short tags are enabled and I have tried with and without

Answer (score -1):

OK, i managed to solve this by declaring the variables globally, so they are available to all views.

```
        // gather data for view
        $view_data = array(
            'due_check_data' => $combined_checks,
            'check_cats'     => $this->check_model->get_check_cats(),
            'page_title'     => 'Due Checks & Tests'
        );

        $this->load->vars($view_data);
        $this->load->view('checks/due_checks');
```